# PostgreSQL returns wrong values for varchar-timestamp conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been encountering a very strange error while working on a postgre server. I have a column which contains times as `varchar` in the format *HH24MMSS* and I have to convert it to a timestamp using `to_timestamp(varchar, 'HH24MMSS')`. However, it returns me wrong values and I cannot understand why. Here are a few examples:

```
Select to_timestamp('111111', 'HH24MMSS')
```

-> 11:00:11

```
Select to_timestamp('000000', 'HH24MMSS')
```

-> 00:00:00

```
Select to_timestamp('122317', 'HH24MMSS')
```

-> 12:06:49

Here A Short Overview:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot offer more detailed information about the server since I am not the admin nor the one maintaining it. I only know that it is Postgre 9.2. I really do not understand, what is wrong here. I would appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: Consult the [`to_timestamp` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html) on what `MM` means.

Comment: Yeah you might want to consider MI (minutes), not MM (months)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. The "MM" is part of the problem and explains why the minutes have not been translated correctly. However, using the correct function with 'MI' instead of 'MM' still delivers weird values. For some reasons, postgre automatically adds 6:32 to add time:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pynd2.png)